# Question Gets Duplicated When Loading More Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I quickly scroll to the bottom of questions,  then while it is loading more questions I try to continue scrolling down, it causes the last question in the list to get duplicated. I'm running Android 4.1.2.

It doesn't happen every time but isn't hard for me to reproduce if I try, although it still does happen randomly. You can see in the screenshot below one of the questions shows up twice. To reproduce:

1. Quickly scroll to the bottom of a list
2. While the loading icon is spinning, continue trying to scroll down
3. When the next set of questions load, the first one is a duplicate of the last

[image: Duplicate question]

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this on 0.1.26.

Comment: I'm on 0.1.27 and running  Android 4.1.2

Comment: Just updated to .27, still no luck. Android 4.3, here.

Comment: I guess that's possibly why you can't?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce it on Android 4.3.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were times where the same question can show up multiple times on the question list.  This was very obvious on high activity sites like Stack Overflow.  The next build should de-duplicate questions in the list.

Look for this in v0.1.31

Comment: Didn't mean to mark as answer yet. I'll try again when v0.1.31 gets pushed out and confirm. Thank you for the update.

Comment: Marking as answer as I am unable to reproduce on version 0.1.31